# pyrogram: for msg in await app.get_history(chat, limit=1): AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_history'

Tags: python-3.x

```py
import time
import pyrogram

app = pyrogram.Client("my_account", api_id=********,
                      api_hash="***********ffe01e582ef")

@app.on_message(pyrogram.filters.command('start', prefixes='.') & pyrogram.filters.me)
async def sms(_, msg):
    with app:
        public = await app.get_chat('@public_name')
        chat = public.id
        while True:
            for msg in await app.get_history(chat, limit=1):
                if msg.text == 'Menu:':
                    await app.send_message(chat, '1')
                else:
                    await app.send_message(chat, '2')
                break
            time.sleep(2)

app.run()
```

i run this code in vscode and his work. but if i try to run this in debian 10 i have this one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update pyrogram and try using this: get_chat_history()

Documentation:
https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_chat_history?highlight=history#pyrogram.Client.get_chat_history

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem.

Pyrogram version 1.4.15 was installed locally and the "app.get_history(chat_id)" method worked in it.

When I updated the Pyrogram to version 2.0.62 I got an error: "'Client' object has no attribute 'get_history'".
Error because the new version requires the "get_chat_history" method.
Documentation:
https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_chat_history

Usage example:
https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/examples/get_chat_history
I hope the advice will be useful.